# jQuery Cycle not loading in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

Does anyone know why jQuery cycle is not loading on this page in IE8?  Works fine in IE9, and all other modern browsers.  I'm totally stumped.  I've used jQuery cycle in a similar way on other pages and it has been fine in IE8:

http://yatestaphouse.hhdev.hothousemarketing.com

Comment: There aren't any javascript errors, which is the confusing part.

Comment: It turned out I was using a <section> tag inside each of the <div>'s I was rotating.  I'm including the HTML5 Shiv for IE <= 8, but it still broke Cycle for some reason.  Would have posted this as an answer but it won't let answer my own question within 7 hours of asking.